# create a clientcontext if legacyauth is false

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, client

How to create a client context if legacyauthprotocol is set to false.without changing the legacyauthprotocol using csom.

Answer (score 1):

This a very common issue which we often face when `LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled` is set to `False` in the SPO tenant. It also affects us when we have configured Multi-factor Authentication (MFA) in our tenant.

1) To authenticate to SPO then, we can use the `GetWebLoginClientContext` method of SharePoint PnP Core library which is available as a nuget package.

So, modify your code as below:

```
using (var context = new AuthenticationManager().GetWebLoginClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test"))
{
    context.Load(context.Web, web => web.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Your site title is: " + context.Web.Title);
}
```

Add [SharePointPnPCoreOnline](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline) Nuget package in your CSOM application. After that, you will be able to login to the SPO env. Basically, this will give you a prompt to enter your details in a browser window.

2) You can also use the `GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext` method of PnP CSOM core and pass the client id and secret using which you can get the client context.

After that you can use the code as below:

```
string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/";
string clientId = "<client-id>";
string clientSecret = "<client-secret>";

using (var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl,clientId,clientSecret))
{       
    Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
    ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;
    clientContext.Load(collList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

References - [Authenticate SharePoint using PnP Authentication Manager](http://www.ktskumar.com/2016/05/authenticate-sharepoint-using-pnp-authentication-manager/)

[Expose on public web your SharePoint Online information](https://ypcode.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/expose-on-public-web-your-sharepoint-online-information/)

Comment: hey @saimonesh, hope it helped you. You can [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by ticking the checkmark besides the answer.